# Enable and Enforce SSL but allow independent ASPX page to use SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke website set up with Enable SSL and Enforce SSL to allow us to have both insecure pages and secure pages such as the shopping cart.

However, I have an independent ASPX page (a PayPal IPN listener) that I want to be able to access through `https://`

At the moment, when a request is made to the IPN listener through SSL an HTML page containing javascript redirection code is served up to redirect to `http://`. Since PayPal's request doesn't respond to javascript redirects, the correct page is never requested.

Is it possible to enable SSL for this file?

**EDIT: Added information about javascript redirect. Also, I have tried creating a virtual directory, but that does not allow me to use DNN application code in my aspx file.**

Answer (score 1):

What version of DNN?  As technically I didn't think redirects should be impacting actual physical .aspx pages.

However, regardless you could put that file inside of a separate folder, then make it a virtual directory and that should block DNN's processing of the request.

Comment: I'm using DNN 6 (latest version). I will give the virtual directory a try.

Comment: The virtual directory didn't help - I use DNN application code to add roles to users and this wouldn't work when the file was in a separate application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two simple things to overcome this:

- Make sure your page is inherited from `DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase`
- In the aspx page, implement a PreRender method that will check request protocol and set response code to 301

Let me know if you need more help

-- Updated --
Locate at siteUrls.config in root and try adding following before `</Rules></RewriterConfig>`:

```
<RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*PageName.aspx(.*)
            <SendTo>~/PageName.aspx$1
        </RewriterRule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by implementing a PreRender method? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I've tried inheriting `DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase` and adding a `Page_PreRender` method that checks for `https` in the url and uses `Response.RedirectPermanent` to redirect to `http`. However, I'm still getting the same DNN javascript redirect, not my 301 response. And other ideas?

Comment: That's may be because you set Force SSL from site settings?

Comment: Yes - as mentioned in my original question I need to have Force SSL enabled to allow navigation from secure pages to non-secure pages.

Comment: Sorry, still nothing. The DNN redirection seems to be occurring before any code I use.

Comment: Gotcha, 'IsSecure' for custom page. So, you need to create a new dnn page and then create a module to implement your custom logic.

Comment: The problem is that we have existing PayPal subscriptions (from before we turned on `Enforce SSL` in the site settings) that use this IPN URL and there is no way of changing that, so we must use the current URL, which is in the form of `https://www.example.com/DesktopModules/PayPal/PayPalIPN.aspx`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat] if you are available right now(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19220/discussion-between-prashant-lakhlani-and-c-cam108)